# Ansible VMWare not clean datastore

Tags: ansible, vmware, esxi

I wrote 2 Ansible playbooks to create and destroy a vm inside an ESXi instance.

The create task is:

```yaml
- name: Clone the template
  delegate_to: localhost
  community.vmware.vmware_guest:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    cluster: "{{ vcenter_cluster_name }}"
    datacenter: "{{ vcenter_datacenter_name }}"
    folder: "{{ vcenter_datacenter_folder }}"
    datastore: "{{ vcenter_datastore }}"
    validate_certs: False
    name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    template: "{{ vm_template }}"
    state: poweredon
    wait_for_ip_address: yes
    networks:
      - name: "DSwitch_Dati-VM Network 869"
        ip: "{{ ansible_host }}"
        netmask: "{{ vm_netmask }}"
        gateway: "{{ vm_gateway }}"
        start_connected: yes
```

The delete playbook is:

```yaml
- name: TMS Cleaner
  hosts: all
  remote_user: tms
  tasks:
    - name: Set powerstate of virtual machine to poweroff
      delegate_to: localhost
      community.vmware.vmware_guest:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: False
        name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        state: poweredoff

    - name: Remove virtual machine from inventory
      delegate_to: localhost
      community.vmware.vmware_guest:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        folder: "{{ vcenter_datacenter_folder }}"
        datastore: "{{ vcenter_datastore }}"
        validate_certs: False
        name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        delete_from_inventory: True
        state: absent
```

The creation is correct, while deletion can correctly stop and remove the vm BUT it doeas not remove the folder from the datastore.

What should I do to have a full deletion of all files related to a vm?

Comment: The delete_from_inventory parameter is the parameter for removing the VM from inventory only. You want to delete the VM files from a datastore, please remove the delete_from_inventory parameter or set it to false.

Comment: I would like to obtain both remotion to bring the esxi instance back to the state before the vm existed. Without that parameter I can obtain this?

Comment: Can you please let me know the meaning of the `ESXi instance back to the state before the vm existed`?  I’m understanding in the purpose as you want to delete all VMs from the ESXi and datastore. Is this correct?

Comment: I would like to run the creation playbook against an host definition to create the vm (and relative datastore folder); then use clean playbook against the same host definition to **completely** remove the files related to that vm. I think that vm deletion should also clean its datastore files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the files deleted also from **datastore** you need to remove the following line:

```
delete_from_inventory: True
```

The ansible documentation for [this module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_guest_module.html) says:

delete_from_inventory:

Choices: Whether to delete Virtual machine from inventory or delete from disk.
**no | yes**

Only remove that line and files will be deleted from datastore.

Comment: I haven't understood well the description of that parameter, actually. So, if I want to remove both the vm from inventory and its files from datastore, do I need 2 task (the first with `delete_from_inventory` at True and the second at False)?

Comment: Yes, the doc. is kind of confusing. In order to fully remove your VM only delete this line: ```delete_from_inventory: True```. This will remove the files from Datastore and also will remove from inventory.